# CoefficientRules numericizing parameters

Tags: symbolic, polynomials

I ran into a problem with `CoefficientRules` behaving differently with exact and numerical coefficients, where in the numerical case it behaves as if the entire expression had an `N[...]` around it, numericizing all numbers, including indices.

E.g.,

```
CoefficientRules[A[0] x + A[1] y + 1, {x, y}]
```

works as intended, but

```
CoefficientRules[A[0] x + A[1] y + 1., {x, y}]
```

does not, as it has `A[0.]` and `A[1.]` in the result.

Is there an easy way to stop this from happening or to convert back the wrong results to their correct form?

Edit: one general workaround I found is to use subscripts such as `Subscript[A,0]` instead of expressions that could be interpreted as function evaluations. That also works with multiple indices and non-integer parameters, for which some of the other suggested workarounds do not.

Comment: I'd call this a bug and report it to Wolfram Support. For comparison, both `CoefficientList` and `CoefficientArrays`, which effectively carry out the same task as `CoefficientRules` but present their result differently, behave in the way you expect, I.e. they do not numericise indices. Perhaps one of those could be used as a workaround as well.

Comment: Maybe set attributes of `A` to `NHoldAll`?

Comment: Another workaround is just to round indices: `CoefficientRules[A[0] x + A[1] y + 1., {x, y}] /. A[n_] :> A[Round[n]]` or more generally `CoefficientRules[A[0] x + A[1] y + 1., {x, y}] /. f_[n_] :> f[Round[n]]`

Comment: Kind of a PIA if one of your coefficients is numeric & exact, like `2` or `Sqrt[2]` or `2/3` etc.

Comment: With respect to a bug, a straight `Trace[CoefficientRules[A[0] x + A[1] y + 1., {x, y}]]` (or `traceView2[..]`-- look up on site) shows it's intentional. But if so, the docs should point it out, which should be reported/suggested to WRI.

Comment: It is not a bug for `N` to convert integers to reals. Typically, it would be a bug if it failed to do that. Exceptions use variations of `NHoldXXX` to block `N`. Also there is `Power`, which is implicitly `N`-holding for its second argument.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Daniel Lichtblau's workaround, which can be done temporarily:

```
Block[{A},
 SetAttributes[A, NHoldAll];
 CoefficientRules[A[0] x + A[1] y + 1., {x, y}]    (* A N-protected *)
 ]
CoefficientRules[A[0] x + A[1] y + 1., {x, y}]
(*
  {{1, 0} -> A[0], {0, 1} -> A[1], {0, 0} -> 1.}   (* A N-protected *)
  {{{1, 0} -> A[0.], {0, 1} -> A[1.], {0, 0} -> 1.}
*)
```

Another way is to use `CoefficientList` and convert the output to rules:

```
With[{coeff = 
   SparseArray@CoefficientList[A[0] x + A[1] y + 1., {x, y}]},
 Thread[coeff@"NonzeroPositions" - 1 -> coeff@"NonzeroValues"]
 ]
(*
  {{0, 0} -> 1., {0, 1} -> A[1], {1, 0} -> A[0]}  
*)
```

With `CoefficentList` exact numeric coefficients are left intact:

```
Block[{A},
 SetAttributes[A, NHoldAll];
 CoefficientRules[A[0] x + Sqrt[2] A[1] y + 1., {x, y}]
 ]
(*  {{1, 0} -> A[0], {0, 1} -> 1.41421 A[1], {0, 0} -> 1.}  *)

With[{coeff = 
   SparseArray@
    CoefficientList[A[0] x + Sqrt[2] A[1] y + 1., {x, y}]},
 Thread[coeff@"NonzeroPositions" - 1 -> coeff@"NonzeroValues"]
 ]
(*  {{0, 0} -> 1., {0, 1} -> Sqrt[2] A[1], {1, 0} -> A[0]}  *)
```